# Problems with rs 232 DB9 pin toggling code

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

In the code below

```
int ctr,fd,j1;
fd =open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    j1=ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &ctr);
if(ctr & TIOCM_DTR)
        {
            ctr&=~TIOCM_DTR;            
            j2=ioctl(fd,TIOCMSET,&ctr);
        }
else
        {   
            ctr=ctr|TIOCM_DTR;          
            j4=ioctl(fd,TIOCMSET,&ctr);
        }
```

1) Can someone explain what ctr= ctr | TIOCM_DTR do? Does it just change the state of DTR pin? because ctr is just an intiger whereas TIOCM_DTR is a bit, right?

2) I have configured the DTR pin to toggle, but while testing even the RTS pin is also toggling.

3) Now if I set a time period between toggling, the code works if the time period is between 1 ms to 50 ms, above 50 ms , the time period when viewed in a DSO is changing between 50 ms to 100 ms and some time even in micro second range.(This time period between toggling is generated through a different timer program, such that whenever the timer overflows, the toggling program is called)

Comment: The line `ctr=ctr|TIOCM_DTR;` does absolutely nothing because execution only reaches that point `if(ctr & TIOCM_DTR)`, which means that the bit is already set.

Comment: Ok, that looks better. So the next question is whether you're allowed to use TIOCM_DTR with TIOCMSET and TIOCMGET.  It's not clear from the header that I have, which shows TIOCM_DTR being used with TIOCMODG and TIOCMODS.

Comment: @ user3386109 which header file should I look into? Further I dont get any error while compiling or running. I get an o/p but as I have written in the question, it is not perfect.

Comment: You can `grep` in the system headers for TIOCM_DTR, or use the `show definition` feature of your IDE/code editor.

Comment: *"2) I have configured the DTR pin to toggle, but while testing even the RTS pin is also toggling."* -- What are you actually trying to do?  Normally the **flow control** (either software XON/XOFF or hardware RTS/CTS) is performed by the **line discipline** that is layered between the serial port driver and the application code (using canonical mode).  IIRC there are some **modem** control settings that may affect the DTR/DCD pins.

Comment: Thanks, I shall look into it

Answer (score 0):

1）"ctr=ctr | TIOCM_DTR" will set the interrelated bit of ctr to 1.

Comment: you mean , the bit which signifies TIOCM_DTR?

Comment: You can check the definition of TIOCM_DTR in the .h file.